# How to add x and y axes tick marks on a plot

Tags: python

I am trying to add x and y tick marks for my plot. How can I do that?

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDexL.png)

Here is the code:..................................................

**Code:**

```
comparison1 = testing_data_points_unscaled[["Climate change (kg CO2 eq.)"]]
PL_new1 = comparison1.rename(columns={"Climate change (kg CO2 eq.)": "Actual Climate change (De-normalized) (kg CO2 eq.)"})
k1=PL_new1.head(1000)

comparison2 = prediction_DE_normalized["Predicted Climate change (De-normalized) (kg CO2 eq.)"]

kk1=comparison2.head(1000)
result1 = pd.concat([k1, kk1], axis=1)
result1
Actual Climate change (De-normalized) (kg CO2 eq.)  Predicted Climate change (De-normalized) (kg CO2 eq.)
18  0.0828  0.092219
171 0.3220  0.328326
107 0.1730  0.188381
98  0.0617  0.072831
178 0.1160  0.097912
plt.style.use('seaborn-deep')
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (90, 35)

plotdata = pd.DataFrame(result1)
plotdata.plot(kind="bar")
plt.legend(loc=0, prop={'size': 50})


plt.title("Actual Vs. Predicted Climate Change", fontsize=70)
plt.xticks(rotation=0)
plt.xlabel("Index", fontsize=50)
plt.ylabel("kg CO2 eq.)", fontsize=50,labelpad=40) #labelpad is to make a space between the label and the numbers

plt.tick_params(labelsize=60)
plt.grid(False)


ax = plt.gca() 
ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
ax.yaxis.offsetText.set_fontsize(50)
```

Comment: You can add ticks using the `plt.xticks` function. Bsides rotation, it also takes in `ticks` and `labels`. Using `plt.xticks([1,2,3], ["A","B","C"])` will plot the labels A, B and C at the position of 1,2,3. The same can be done with yticks

Comment: Thx, there's no automated way that don't require the user to add each label?

Comment: Well, there is and that's what's already visible in the output, right? Or perhaps I misunderstand your question.

Comment: There are no visible ticks in the output I posted.

Answer (score 0):

The ticks are there, just that it is very small and you cannot see it. The reason is that you have set the figure size to `(90, 35)`. Some other items like title (`fontsize=70`) are set to higher numbers.

You can get the tick size by running `ax.xaxis.majorTicks[0].tick1line.get_markersize()` and `ax.yaxis.majorTicks[0].tick1line.get_markersize()`. It should give you the default of `3.5`, which is pretty small. So, increase the tick size by adding this line after the `plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = ...`

```
plt.rcParams["xtick.major.size"] = 50 ## Adjust to what you need
plt.rcParams["ytick.major.size"] = 50 ## Adjust to what you need
```

After the line `ax=plt.gca()`, add these lines, in case the ticks are not seen because they are white or are too thin.

```
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='black', width=10, which='both')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='black', width=10, which='both')
```

The plot (with the data you gave will look like this...

[image]

Comment: Thx, I've tried it, this is only creating a gap between the x axis/y axis values and the axis itself- not a tick mark.

Comment: I forgot to add the last 4 lines in my code (now added), maybe these are the lines that are creating the discrepancy between your generated results and mine?

Comment: Added a couple of lines to set tick width and color, in case the ticks are in white. Change the numbers for the rcparams and tick width to see if it helps show the lines

Comment: Thx, yet still no ticks are visible. The thing is when I do (I know it's wrong) `plt.xticks(rotation=0, width=50)` I can see the tick marks on an empty plot with an error message.